# merge dataframes based on column A OR B

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I need to merge two dataframes, but the merge can be made on either two columns of the right-hand dataframe.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['a', 'b', 'c']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : ['a', 'b', np.nan], 'col_b' : ['z', np.nan, 'c']})
df_1.merge(df_2, how = 'left', left_on = 'col', right_on = 'col_a')
```

In the example above, the merge is finding a match for `col == 'a'` and `col == 'b'`, because `df_2` contains those values in its `col_a` column. But I would also like it to find the match with the `col_b == 'c'` of `df_2`. If regex worked with merge, a good solution would look this way:

```
df_1.merge(df_2, how = 'left', left_on = 'col', right_on = 'col_a|col_b')
```

The output should look like this:

```
col col_a   col_b
a    a      z
b    b      NaN
c    NaN    c
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what we are looking for here is to merge twice, concatenate the results and drop any duplicates that might result from `col_a` and `col_b` being the same.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['a', 'c', 'b']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : ['b', np.nan, 'a', 'a', 'c'], 'col_b' : [np.nan, 'c', 'z', 'b', 'c']})

df = (
    pd.concat([
        df_1.merge(df_2, left_on='col', right_on='col_a'),
        df_1.merge(df_2, left_on='col', right_on='col_b'),
    ]).drop_duplicates()
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(df)
#   col col_a col_b
# 0   a     a     z
# 1   a     a     b
# 2   c     c     c
# 3   b     b   NaN
# 4   c   NaN     c
# 5   b     a     b
```

We see we deal with:

1. `a` matches `col_a` twice
2. `b` matches `col_a` and `col_b` separately (including a row that matches `a`)
3. `c` matches `col_a` and `col_b` at the same time but isn't duplicated in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform both merges and use `combine_first` to fuse the two merges:

```
(df_1.merge(df_2, left_on='col', right_on='col_a', how='left')
     .combine_first(df_1.merge(df_2, left_on='col', right_on='col_b', how='left'))
)
```

output:

```
  col col_a col_b
0   a     a     z
1   b     b   NaN
2   c   NaN     c
```

Other example (without the pitfall of the already aligned index):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['a', 'c', 'b']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : ['b', np.nan, 'a'], 'col_b' : [np.nan, 'c', 'z']})
```

output:

```
  col col_a col_b
0   a     a     z
1   c   NaN     c
2   b     b   NaN
```

Comment: What if either merge is 1-to-n e.g. if `df_2` has `a` twice in `col_a`?  Won't `combine_first` have trouble then?  Also we should remove rows that are `NaN` in `col_a` and `col_b`.

Comment: @KyleParsons in this case we need OP to defined rules on how to merge as it is not trivial, so I assumed this is not a constraint, but you're right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lest try join given your output

```
 df_1.join(df_2)
```

output

```
col col_a   col_b
0   a   a   z
1   b   b   NaN
2   c   NaN c
```

Or

```
df_1.merge(df_2, how='left', left_on='col', right_on='col_a').combine_first(df_2)
```

output

```
col col_a col_b
0   a     a     z
1   b     b   NaN
2   c   NaN     c
```

Comment: This only works by chance here as the indexes are already aligned. Try with `df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : ['b', np.nan, 'a'], 'col_b' : [np.nan, 'c', 'z']})`.

Comment: no it doesn't, as `combine_first` also works based on index ;)

Comment: Try with `df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['a', 'c', 'b']}) ; df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : ['b', np.nan, 'a'], 'col_b' : [np.nan, 'c', 'z']})`, the output is incorrect (a `z` will end up in a `b` row)